# Добавить столбец в строку Bootstrap-сетки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Я пытаюсь вставить в строку сетки новый столбец. Для этого я проделываю следующее:

```
$('#photos')[0].children[rowCount - 1].append(...);
```

Элемент, обозначенный троеточием, имеет следующий вид:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/b/b/7/bb7e3d5affbc18201336387c588cb6ca63c1282d.jpg"/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-md-center">
            <a href="">Удалить</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-break">имя_файла.jpg</div>
    <div>Диагноз:</div>
    <div>Вероятность:</div>
</div>
```

В результате на страницу вставляется не блок, а его HTML-код, который я передаю в качестве параметра в методе append. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После `[0]` у вас уже идет кусок "чистого" JS, а не jQuery. А `jQuery.append()` немного отличается от "чистого" `.append();`. Чтобы вставить HTML, первый может получить в качестве аргумента и целый Node-элемент, и его HTML в виде строки. А второй - только элемент:

```js
$('.mama').append( document.createElement('div') );
$('.mama').append( "<div></div>" );

document.querySelector('.mama').append( document.createElement('div') );
// Предыдущие 3 нормально сработают. 
document.querySelector('.mama').append( "<div></div>" ); // вставится строка
```

```css
.mama div { display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mama"></div>
```

Если хочется добавить HTML-строку, можно использовать `insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
var mama = document.querySelector('.mama');

mama.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div></div>');
```

```css
.mama div { display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="mama"></div>
```

Или, всю вашу строчку можно записать через jQuery:

```
$('#photos').eq(0).children().eq(rowCount - 1).append(...);
```

`eq()` также достаёт элемент с указанным индексом, но возвращает jQuery-объект, для которого будут работать методы jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо! Последний вариант подошел для меня

Answer (score 0):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

// функция для примера ради контента
const template = elem => `<li>${elem}</li>`

let i = 0;
        
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // пример вставки шаблона из строки для примера
  content.innerHTML += template(i); // <-- тут может быть ваш шаблон
  i++;
})
```

```html
<button class="button">add</button>

<ul class="content"></ul>
```